# String.Replace doublequotes with singleqoutes

Tags: c#, string, iframe

I am taking iFrame code from the database and assigning it to a string

```
var videoCode = details.Tables["MarketingDetails"].Rows[0]["MarketingVideo"].ToString();

videoCode=videoCode.Replace("\"","'");
```

While debugging, the value of videocode is:

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8GRDA1gG8R8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

When I attempt to the do the Replace the value of the `"` stays the same. How do I correclly replace the Double Quotes with Single qoutes?

Comment: where in the string do you see a `"\"` backslash 
`videoCode=videoCode.Replace("\"","'");` use the debugger Inspect this value and paste exactly what it is after this line 
`var videoCode = details.Tables["MarketingDetails"].Rows[0]["MarketingVideo"].ToString();`

Comment: how else can you use a double quote in the replace? @DJKRAZE

Comment: I think you need `.Replace('\"', ''');`
Note that those are single ticks around the char for the escape double " and then again aroung the single tick (ie single tick \" single tick, single tick x3)

Comment: have you tried something like this 
`videoCode=videoCode.Replace.Replace("\"", "\\\"");`

Comment: @alykins best comment...ever. I keep reading tock in there somehow

Comment: @alykins yours doesnt close the '' im guessing you meant `.Replace('"','\'');

@DJKRAZE is the second value in ur replae for single qoutes?

Comment: @CoreyToolis Does my solution not work?

Comment: @CalvinSmith no for some reason it will not change it.

Comment: @CoreyToolis Sorry, you need to escape the single tick as well. Corrected. Also assign the string as replace will not replace the value for the string if it's not assigned. `string x = string.Format("{0} {1}", '\"', '\'');
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            x = x.Replace('\"', '\'');
            Console.WriteLine(x);
`
Output is 
`" '` 
`' '`

Comment: @CoreyToolis Why do you want to do it? What is wrong with your string?

Comment: I am trying to take my iframe value and use html parsing to set the src of a video on the page. I need to get the src from the string. 

it keeps giving me a null reference error. I am thinking if they are single quotes it may work correctly.

Comment: @CoreyToolis To parse your html you can use a real Html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). No need for string tricks to get the `src` BTW: For your simple case, Regex is also enough..

Comment: `I am thinking if they are single quotes it may work correctly` typical [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem)

Comment: @L.B i am using htmlAgilitypack if i try and just use the string it gives an object refernce error.

Comment: @CoreyToolis How do you expect me to help without knowing what you are doing?

Comment: because all i was trying to do was manipulate the string. I was hoping that being able to do that would fix the reference error.

Comment: @CoreyToolis I never get this error with HtmlAgilityPack, so I don't know how you use it. But let me ask it to my crystall ball.

Answer (score 0):

Its very much a work around but one way to do it.

```
char doubleQuote = '"';

char singleQuote = '\'';

viedeoCode = VideoCode.Replace(doubleQuote,singleQuote);
```

Comment: I would modify this to be `char doubleQuote = '\"';` but really creating the objects is redundant (I think*) as the escapes can just be plugged in.

Comment: your possibly right, its just the way it was written was very confusing, especially DJKRAZE answer. Ive never been against adding 1-2 lines to make it more simple and less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i Needed to use HtmlEntitys DeEntitize on the value pulled back from the database.

videoCode = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(videoCode);